# Sorting Strings using Collections.sort?

Tags: java, string, sorting

I'm attempting to sort two strings using the collection.sort() method, but I'm having issues understanding the logic of the implementation. Here is what I have so far. Are there any issues with my implementation? 
Note: I want to sort them alphabetically:
"Apple" > "Orange"

```
Collections.sort(mailbox.getMessages() , (String a, String b) -> {
    if (String.valueOf(a.charAt(0)) > String.valueOf(b.charAt(0))) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (String.valueOf(a.charAt(0)) <
        String.valueOf(b.charAt(0))) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes there are issues. Try compiling it and see what it says,

Comment: Only issue I could see is if either `a` or `b` has a possibility of being `null`. You should also only perform 1 comparison between characters and store that result.

Comment: @Obicere: and the fact that it only sorts on the first characters. In general a string is sorted lexicographical.

Comment: Why not use the plain `Collections.sort()` method? That will sorts string lexicographically anyway. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I'm getting a "bad operand type error" after compilation. I thought that the int value of the characters could be compared using ">" , "<" etc.

Comment: @CommuSoft He may only want to sort on first characters. Given just his code though, it is hard to say for certain.

Comment: @DNA it seems OP want to compare only for first character, hence be equals if first is the same even if others are not.

Comment: Note that you only need that one if statement, if the statement is false then the other condition has to be true

Comment: Oh! I see! I didn't realize that the CompareTo() method for Strings was lexographic. Thank you! That should fix it.

Comment: @TameHog: that's not true: if `a < b` fails, that doesn't mean `a > b`, because `a == b` is a possibility as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implements a `Comparable<String>` which is implemented as a *lexicographical* comparison, in other words, by default `"Apple".compareTo("Orange") < 0`. So the default is sufficient.

Now [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) has a variant that takes this comparator into account, you can thus simply use:

```
Collections.sort(mailbox.getMessages());
```

---

About your own implementation:

You shouldn't use `String.valueof` to cast back to a string: you can compare `char`s with the `<`, but you can't use this operator on `String`s. Furthermore your implementation is not **recursive**: if the two *first* characters are equal, that doesn't mean the `String`'s are equal *per se*, for instance `"Apple"` and `"Ambiguous"`. So you would have to implement a more complex comparator.

Comment: Thanks! I misread the API and I didn't see that compareTo() was lexographic

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare `String` with the symbol `>`. You can simply do :

```
Collections.sort(mailbox.getMessages(), (String a, String b) -> {
     return Character.compare(a.charAt(0), b.charAt(0));
});
```

Note that this will sort according only to first character. If you want to sort on the entire string value lexographically then you can simply use `Collections.sort(mailbox.getMessages())` as `String` already implements `Comparable`.

Comment: Why not just `Character.compare(a.charAt(0), b.charAt(0))` then?